# Windows 10 - Super slow Updates

Tags: ssd, windows-update

Using Windows 10 Pro x64 in a business.

A few users now have had long updates when first turning on their computers- I'm talking 2 hours to all morning.

The main one we see is 'Configuring Windows Features, 100% complete'. The circle spins for hours.

The other one has an increasing percentage with a similar phrase, Working on Updates.

We've had this on Latitude E5470 with SSD and HDD, Optiplex 3040 SFF/Micro, And Dell XPS 13. Is this normal? With more users on Windows 10 and updates taking this long, the whole business could be without computers for an entire morning!

I'm hoping that it's very much a one off; a single type of update that takes a long time, with each subsequent update being ok?

These updates are all downloaded from Windows Update.

Comment: What is your download speed? The longest procedure is usually downloading the update.

Comment: It downloads before the update commences, surely? 100Mbps, tests generally come back 80-90Mbps.

Comment: Ow sorry I completetly read that wrong. Sometimes you can still press ctrl + alt + del to still get to the login screen. It usually continues the update install once your logged in. Windows 10 updates are still a thing. I recommend to disable every 'Upgrade' not update but upgrade in a business. These are usually the main cause of issues.

Comment: May be they are downloading and exchanging updates on the LAN, the feature can be buggy (see : http://www.digitalcitizen.life/sites/default/files/gdrive/win10_download_updates/windows_update_4.jpg). As a fix you may want to configure Windows to "defer" updates and do them outside of business hours (& week-ends)

Comment: What frustrates is that this was never a problem for other versions of Windows. If the update takes 4 hours, that's still 4 hours of inconvenience, no matter where we shift it to! Good idea on the LAN update point, I'll try that.

Comment: turning wifi off while on this update screen, caused the logon screen to appear after about 30 seconds. perhaps it is the LAN thing. I will test and turn this off in future.

Comment: Ok, this feature wasn't actually enabled, so perhaps it was a coincidence. will test anyway.